# Close and Reopen PDF's in C

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to write a function that when called, notes what pdf's are open in Acrobat, closes them, runs something else that will modify those files, and then reopens them.

Currently I am getting a bunch of `HWND`'s and storing them in global variables accessed in `close_pdfs()`. This is shown below (I know I've been lazy and have magic numbers, just trying to get it working):

```
char windows[16][64]; // up to 16 windows with name length 64
int n_windows;
HWND tobedestroyed[16];
...
...
void close_pdfs() {
    n_windows = 0;
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i< n_windows; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", windows[i]);
        DestroyWindow(tobedestroyed[i]);
    }
}

void reopen_pdfs() {
    //this should iterate and reopen the closed pdf's
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    char title[80];
    GetWindowText(hwnd,title,sizeof(title));
    if (!strcmp(&title[strlen(title)-4], ".pdf")) {
        strcpy(windows[n_windows], title);
        tobedestroyed[n_windows] = hwnd;
        n_windows ++;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

These are called by:

```
close_pdfs();
system("modify_pdfs.exe");
reopen_pdfs();
```

Currently I can't get the pdf's to close, however I also think it is likely that there are better ways to tackle this problem.

Any help on how to complete this task as described in the first paragraph would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Question specifies C, tag specifies C++. Choose one. I assume C, but my unfamiliarity with the Windows API stops me from editing.

Comment: The tag should be `C` not `C++`

Comment: This is what the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-closewindow) says: *"Minimizes (but does not destroy) the specified window."* Not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: The code compiles perfectly fine using either gcc or g++, specifying one or the other is pedantic and limits potential solutions. The purpose of the code is specified in the first paragraph, if there are errors then that is another issue.

Comment: @KJ SumatraPDF is a clean solution to the problem, especially given that its source code is all freely available. Thanks!